# Labelling two separate data frames by row and then merging them into one data frame under the same column but with row labels preserved

Tags: r, dataframe, label, row

I have two data sets, lets call them

```
A: 1, 3, 5, 6, 3
```

and

```
B: 2, 4, 7, 9, 8
```

Where the numbers in `A` and `B` represent time

I want to label all of the numbers in A by **row** as "positive"
and all numbers in B labelled "Negative" by **row**.

I then want to merge both A and B into a single data frame under one column called "time", but they must keep their row names "Positive"/"Negative" for their corresponding number so I can plot both onto a survival plot

Comment: Can you clarify a little? Is your data.frame one column with `1,3,5,6,3` in it, or do you have 5 columns? Ideally, if you can show some simplified code like `A <- data.frame(var=c(1,3,5,6,3))` that will assist to make sure answers will be helpful.

Comment: Rownames in R _must_ be distinct, so you will need to accept the fact that your request is impossible. You should instead expect that you will have a column with 'Negative' or 'Positive' values as requested. Connection of this request to `[survival-analysis]` is so obscure that I deleted the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are looking for such a dataframe:

```
A <- data.frame(time = c(1, 3, 5, 6, 3), status= "positive")
B <- data.frame(time = c(2, 4, 7, 9, 8), status= "negative")

rbind(A, B)
```

Output:

```
   time   status
1     1 positive
2     3 positive
3     5 positive
4     6 positive
5     3 positive
6     2 negative
7     4 negative
8     7 negative
9     9 negative
10    8 negative
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of a new column `status` the status is stored in the unloved `rownames(df)` . At least that's my guess.

Comment: That's true. I will wait for OPs reply.

Comment: @MartinGal See my comment above as to why your guess is incorrect. I would be possible to have row names of a matrix be non-distinct, but that imposes other limitations that would make it undesirable in most circumstances.